# QuickBlox : Already logged in Error after Logout

Tags: quickblox

We are using **QuickBlox's iOS SDK** for chat implementation.

Currently we have only two view controllers *1). Login and 2). UserList*

After successful login app moves to *UserList* view in this view we have **Logout** button.
According to QuickBlox API we have use below method for logout

`[QBUsers logOutWithDelegate:self];`

on button click and its delegate method :

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result
{
    if([result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserLogOutResult class]]) // QuickBlox User Logout result
    {
        // Success result
        if(result.success)
        {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

After successful logout app moves back to login screen.

**Problem :**

When user clicks on logout and app moves to Login screen and again if user input same user name and password then log prints

`Chat App[3183:5903] -[QBChat loginWithUser:] -> return. Already logged in`

How to resolve this issue ? OR What is the best practice to implement Login/Logout flow ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to SDK reference, exist session, simply user login and login to chat.

1) you need create session. You may create it simply:

```
 [QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self];
```

or with extended request:

```
 QBASessionCreationRequest *extendedAuthRequest = [QBASessionCreationRequest request];
 extendedAuthRequest.userLogin = @"garry";
 extendedAuthRequest.userPassword = @"garrySant88";

[QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self];
```

(If you create session with extended request, pass second action)

2) Perform simply login by

```
 [QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:currentUser password:pass delegate:self]
```

3) after that for using chat:

```
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
```

For logout you should perform logout methods in back order.

```
[[QBChat instance] logout];
```

after that:

```
 [QBUsers logOutWithDelegate:self];
```

and:

```
  [QBAuth destroySessionWithDelegate:self];
```

Recreation of session not necessarily. You can create one session and many times login/logout.

Comment: 1+ for `[[QBChat instance] logout];`

Comment: More, How to handle login fail in `[[ChatService instance] loginWithUser:[LocalStorageService shared].currentUser completionBlock:^
            {
 }];` this block

Comment: For this you need assign some class as a delegate to chat 
[QBChat instance].delegate = someClass; and implement its methods. (http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/Protocols/QBChatDelegate.html) like - (void)chatDidNotLogin

Comment: yes its already there `ChatService` but when `Already logged in` error occurred, `completionBlock` did not get called !

Comment: Are you using this? https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat/sample-chat 

Class ChatService does not implement fail block. You need add something like failBlcok and implement it in this class

Comment: Yes, `chatDidNotLogin` is not implemented only `chatDidFailWithError` is implemented

Comment: Something like this: - (void)loginWithUser:(QBUUser *)user completionBlock:(void(^)())completionBlock failBlcok:(void(^)())failBlock;

then add block as a property and invoke in chatDidFailWithError

Comment: ok but how would I get to know the reason of fail like already login, network error etc ?

Comment: also I tried to implement `chatDidNotLogin` method in `ChatService` but it did not called for `Already logged in` error !!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43578/discussion-between-maulik-and-frankwhite)